# Describe the set of all points x1, x2 such that the determinant is zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Consider three distinct points $(a_{1}, a_{2}), (b_{1}, b_{2}), (c_{1}, c_{2})$ in the plane. Describe the set of all points $(x_{1}, x_{2})$ satisfying the equation:

$$det\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\x_{1}&a_{1}&b_{1}&c_{1}\\x_{2}&a_{2}&b_{2}&c_{2}\\x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2& a_{1}^2+a_{2}^2& b_{1}^2+b_{2}^2& c_{1}^2+c_{2}^2\end{pmatrix} = 0$$

I can use cofactor expansion to get one long equation, but that does not let me solve for both $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a geometric interpretation. In short, if $(a_1,a_2),(b_1,b_2),(c_1,c_2)$ are on the same line then the determinant is zero if and only if $(x_1,x_2)$ is also on this line. However if not, then the determinant is equal to zero if and only if $(x_1,x_2)$ is on the circle passing through $(a_1,a_2),(b_1,b_2),(c_1,c_2)$.

Explanation.

The determinant is zero if and only if the rows are independent if and only if there exist constants $C_1,\dots,C_4$, not all zero such that

$$(*)\quad\quad C_1 R_1 +C_2R_2+C_3R_3+C_4R_4=0$$,

where $R_1,\dots,R_4$ are the rows of the matrix.

Two cases.

1. $C_4$ can be chosen to be zero then the first three rows are dependent. This can happen if and only if all four points are on the same line if and only if $(a_1,a_2)$, $(b_1,b_2)$ and $(c_1,c_2)$ are on the same line, and so is $(x_1,x_2)$.
2. $C_4$ cannot be chosen to be zero. Note that in this case the three points cannot be on the same line (otherwise we could choose $C_4=0$), and in particular, they are vertices of a triangle, and there's a unique circle passing through them points.  without loss of generality, $C_4$ can be chosen to be $1$.

Writing the equation $(*)$ column by column gives:

$$C_1 + C_2 x_1+ C_3 x_2 +x_1^2+x_2^2=0$$
$$C_1 + C_2 a_1+ C_3 a_2 +a_1^2+a_2^2=0$$
etc.

Rewrite the equalities by completing to a square to obtain

$$ (x_1+C_2/2)^2 + (x_2+C_3/2)^2 =d$$
$$ (a_1+C_2/2)^2 + (a_2+C_3/2)^2 =d$$
$$ (b_1+C_2/2)^2 + (b_2+C_3/2)^2 =d$$
$$ (c_1+C_2/2)^2 + (c_2+C_3/2)^2 =d$$

where $d=(C_2/2)^2+(C_3/2)^2-C_1.$

Note that $d\ge 0$, otherwise the equalities (which by assumption hold) cannot hold.

What this reads is that all four points are on the circle centered at $(-C_2/2,-C_3/2)$ with radius $\sqrt{d}$ which must be strictly positive, because otherwise the points $(a_1,a_2)$, $(b_1,b_2)$, $(c_1,c_2)$ are the same (automatically on the same line). But there's only one circle passing through $(a_1,a_2),(b_1,b_2),(c_1,c_2)$ (and now we have an expression for its center and radius), and as a result, the determinant is zero if and only if $(x_1,x_2)$ are on this circle.